# Locating Hidden Field Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden-field

Boiled down to the barest element, I just want to set a hidden field's value when I click an element on the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="toggleParent">
  <input type="hidden" name="toggleValue" id="toggleValue" value="closed" />
  <h2>Click Me</h2>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var toggle;
  jQuery('div#toggleParent h2').click(function () {
    if (toggle == '' || toggle == 'open') {
      toggle = 'closed';
    } else {
      toggle = 'open';
    }
    jQuery('div#toggleParent input#toggleValue').val(toggle);
  });
});
```

Obviously, it's not working. (Why would I be here otherwise?) The click event is working fine, as I can step through it in Firebug. But when it gets to setting the value, the code fails. What's more, trying `alert(jQuery('div#toggleParent input#toggleValue').length)` returns 0. In fact, `alert(jQuery('div#toggleParent h2').length)` returns 0 even though the click event on that exact element just fired!

What am I missing?

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  Just attempted this code in jsFiddle, and wouldn't you know it? It works perfectly.  Obviously, there's a problem elsewhere I'm not seeing.  Thanks for taking a look at it anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
document.ready(function () {...});
```

Should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {...});
```

Or even:

```
jQuery(function () {...});
```

Or...

```
jQuery(function ($) { /* Use $ in here instead of jQuery */ });
```

Keep in mind that when using IDs, any other selector is unnecessary since IDs are unique. This is sufficient:

```
jQuery('#toggleValue').val(toggle);
```

Comment: @Box9 Or even: `jQuery(function($) { ... });` (since `$` is cooler than `jQuery`)

Comment: In fact I believe it's better to use the ID selector for performance.

Comment: None of this actually addresses the issue that the code is working EXCEPT for the line that references .val. The code I am using does in fact use jQuery(document).ready -- I simply miscopied it.

Comment: @Roger, there's no reason for it to not work from what we can see. Can you set up a demo of the problem actually occuring?

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  Just attempted this code in jsFiddle, and wouldn't you know it? It works perfectly.  Obviously, there's a problem elsewhere I'm not seeing.  Thanks for taking a look at it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'toggle' value is undefined, you only define it in document.ready, but do not assign any value to it. To assign, use

```
var toggle = jQuery('div#toggleParent input#toggleValue').val();
```

Comment: The undefined isn't a problem; it simply moves into the else block of the if statement. I have stepped through the code, and it doesn't fail until the val assignment, at which point toggle DOES have a value. Also, this doesn't address the issue that the length alerts continually return 0.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var toggleParent = $('#toggleParent')[0],
        toggleValue = $('#toggleValue')[0];

    $(toggleParent).find('h2').click(function() {
        toggleValue.value = toggleValue.value === 'closed' ? 'open' : 'closed';
    });

});
```

Comment: This fails as well. `$('#toggleParent').length` returns 0, so when I try to [0] into this, I get an error.

Comment: @Roger If `$('#toggleParent').length` returns 0, then there is no element with an id "toggleParent" on the page. Have you tried in different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var toggle;
            $('div#toggleParent h2').click(function() {
                if (toggle == '' || toggle == 'open') {
                    toggle = 'closed';
                } else {
                    toggle = 'open';
                }
                $('div#toggleParent input#toggleValue').val(toggle);
                alert($("input#toggleValue").val()); // check what the new value is
            });
        });
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.